# AttributeError: module 'crontab' has no attribute 'CronSlices'

Tags: python, django, redis, cron, celery

I am currently developing a website using Django.
I want to program tasks so I am planning to use Celery and Redis.

I've installed Celery (pip command).
I've also installed Redis using brew and it works: `redis-cli ping`  returns `PONG`.
I had to install `django-celery-result` and `django-celery-beat` (I used pip command).

After setting-up my Django code, I got this error message when I run the server.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_celery_beat/validators.py", line 7, in <module>
    class _CronSlices(crontab.CronSlices):
AttributeError: module 'crontab' has no attribute 'CronSlices'
```

I don't know how to fix this error. Does anyone have an idea of where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 1):

I had been this bug too. I deleted crontab:

```
pip uninstall crontab
```

Then I installed python-crontab:

```
pip install python-crontab
```

It's solved )